# Photo album crashes in iPad2

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am presenting photo album and camera from a UIButton from a UIPopOverController. Both works fine when I present it in `iPad1` running on `iOS 5.1`.

When I do the same thing in `iPad2` running on `iOS 6.0`, the camera works fine but the photo album crashes as in the below image. Also note than the app is a landscape app.

[image]

The code Im using is

```
 //imgPicker.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
popOver.delegate = self;
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:importFromPhotosBtn.frame
                              inView:importFromPhotosBtn
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                            animated:YES];
```

Please someone point me out what went wrong. Im struck up with this for more than half a day. Any timely help is much more appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of the debug log?

Comment: Sorry, nothing found execpt `(lldb)`.

Comment: @Ananth: try to test it on the portrait mode by enabling the portrait mode. Then tell me if the crash is there.

Comment: @Midhun MP, thanks for your response, it works on Portrait mode when enabled,.. but my app is landscape app kno, how can I fix it??

Comment: @Ananth: I have added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Midhum MP's clue, the problem actually was the frame from which I presented the popOver.

The `popOver` size is `320 x 500` but I was presenting it from the rect containing (221, 360) as the origin, So the size messed up (500 + 360  which is greater than the iPad ht in landscape(768)).

But not sure why it runs in iPad1(iOS 5.1) and not in iPad2 (iOS 6)!

So, I just changed the presenting rect (such that it won't've such mess-ups) which works fine now. It fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi ananth r  u there, i need some help because i am facing the same problem? can u guide me  @Ananth

Comment: @Babul, wats the problem you were facing ?

Answer (score 1):

The UIImagePicker is supported on the portrait mode.
Your application supports only landscape mode, that causes the issue.

**Solution:**

1. Subclass UIImagePicker class
2. Implement shouldAutorotate in the subclass

   ```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
   {
      return NO;
   }
   ```
3. Use this subclassed UIImagePicker class for creating picker instead of UIImagePicker

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've already subclassed `UIImagePicker` and using that class only. The problem is due to other reason. But your clue towards the problem really helped me fixing the issue.